# Power SW Pin Connected to Motherboard Disconnected at the other end

Tags: motherboard

So I recently noticed that my power button was not working. I opened up my PC and all Reset SW, LED, and Power SW Pins were connected properly to the motherboard BUT I could see that the other end of the Power SW Pin was disconnected. I don't know where its supposed to be connected and any help and/or video/tutorial links will be appreciated. Thanks! (Intel Desktop Board DH55PJ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your [manual](https://downloadmirror.intel.com/18913/eng/DH55PJ_ProductGuide01_English.pdf).

Page 45 states it connects to pins 6 and 8. It should also be labelled on the board, usually 'PWR_SW' or similar.

[image]

How on earth have you been turning it on if it was disconnected?

Edit: Rereading the question, it sounds like it's disconnected from the switch itself? If so, it's impossible for us to say as this is connected to your case. You'll have to disassemble the case and find the two pins on the back of the switch and solder/attach them. Often they will look like this, but it varies:

[image]

As it's only the switch, it doesn't matter which way around you reattach the wires (unlike an LED, which has a diode preventing it from working the wrong way around)

Comment: The Power SW pin IS connected to the motherboard correctly but the other end which I assume should be connected to the switch itself is disconnected and hanging loosely.

Comment: @RishabaNaushad Just spotted that and amended my answer - It's impossible for us to advise properly as it's specific to your case.

Comment: Okay but can you tell me where its generally connected to? Thanks :D

Comment: @RishabaNaushad Added an image, it'll be behind your front cover of your case.

Comment: @RishabaNaushad No problem, just so you're aware as it's just the switch, the wires can attach to the two pins either way, it doesn't matter. Added that to my answer.